# Add custom colors to TfontDialog in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, winapi

How i can add some values to color Box in the TFontDialog?
Or please tell me about components that can select font with custom color?
I use Delphi 7.

Thanks.

I found some way... But how i can show TColorDialog when color box changed on itemIndex = 0?

```
 procedure TForm1.FontDialog1Show(Sender: TObject);
const
 IDCOLORCMB = $473;
 SMyColorName: PChar = 'clMoneyGreen';
 CMyColor: TColor = clMoneyGreen;
begin
 SendDlgItemMessage(FontDialog1.Handle, IDCOLORCMB, CB_INSERTSTRING, 0,
 Integer(SMyColorName));
 SendDlgItemMessage(FontDialog1.Handle, IDCOLORCMB, CB_SETITEMDATA, 0,
   ColorToRGB(CMyColor));
end;
```

Comment: Write your OWN font dialog. It's not exactly HARD Is it?

Comment: +1 to @Warren P. Now I don't know what type of application the OP is writing, but if font selection is an important operation in the application, then it makes perfect sense to implement a custom font-selection dialog, which is both very easy and fun (I would think -- e.g. have a look at [my custom colour selector](http://privat.rejbrand.se/rejbrandcolourselector1.png)).

Comment: Yes, creation own dialog is not hard, but it is long time... Windows provides good dialog but it no contains "CustomColors"... btw, i found some solution but answer of Andreas Rejbrand may be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this works:

```
interface

TFontDialog = class(Dialogs.TFontDialog)
const
  IDCOLORCMB = $473;
protected
  procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  procedure DoShow; override;
end;

...

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FontDialog1.Execute();
end;

{ TFontDialog }

procedure TFontDialog.DoShow;
const
  SMyColorName: PChar = 'Custom...';
  CMyColor: TColor = $0033ccff;
begin
  SendDlgItemMessage(Handle, IDCOLORCMB, CB_INSERTSTRING, 0, Integer(SMyColorName));
  SendDlgItemMessage(Handle, IDCOLORCMB, CB_SETITEMDATA, 0, ColorToRGB(CMyColor));
end;

procedure TFontDialog.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  with Message do
    if (Msg = WM_COMMAND) and (WParamHi = CBN_SELENDOK) and (WParamLo = IDCOLORCMB) and (SendDlgItemMessage(Handle, IDCOLORCMB, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0) = 0) then
      with TColorDialog.Create(Self) do
        try
          Color := TColor(SendDlgItemMessage(Self.Handle, IDCOLORCMB, CB_GETITEMDATA, 0, 0));
          Options := [cdFullOpen];
          if Execute(Self.Handle) then
            SendDlgItemMessage(Self.Handle, IDCOLORCMB, CB_SETITEMDATA, 0, ColorToRGB(Color));
        finally
          Free;
        end;
end;
```

But notice, as David correctly argues in the comments below, that this code might fail if the dialog box should change (significantly enough) in a future version of Windows. That might or might not be a showstopper for the OP.

Comment: That's extremely naughty, don't you know!

Comment: @David: I am afraid I can't quite tell if that was meant as a joke or actual concern about the approach. I didn't mess up the message processing, did I?

Comment: Well, that makes assumptions about the controls on the dialog that are implementation details. I expect you got the details right, but I think the approach is brittle.

Comment: You can have an up-vote all the same, but I think you would do well to point out the potential problems with running this code on some future version of Windows that changes the dialogs.  Indeed which versions did you test it on?

Comment: @David: Yes, that is quite true. I cannot really argue about that, even though this dialog has been rather inert since Windows 3.1. As for the second Q - you know me: it's Win 7 64-bit nowadays.

Comment: @David: Hm... But do I make any assumption that the VCL source code doesn't do already?

Comment: I think the VCL is taking liberties too!

Comment: I like this solution :) Thanks very much! it work on XP/win2000 too :) but code for D7 looks different (it is no problem)... My solution was to replace the color box, after i add the chosen color in the original color box (which I hid behind the screen) causing the event OnChange.  How much was a bad decision?

Answer (score 2):

`TFontDialog` is a wrapper around the system's common dialog, [`ChooseFont`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646914%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  The common dialog does not offer easy customisation of its colour drop-down.